# No notification when bot replies

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have wrote a simple telegram bot which reads links form messages sent to it and replies with some information.

Use-case is following: I'm viewing some page in Safari, then I click `share` and send an URL to bot.

At this point I'm expecting to see a push notification with information, but instead onlu badge with number 1 appears next to Telegram icon.

I'm, using regular python-telegram-bot lib for Python3.9 and reply to messages with update.message.reply_text

Here is a whole code:

```
import os
import re

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CallbackContext, CommandHandler
from telegram.ext.filters import Filters

TELEGRAM_API_KEY = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_API_KEY")
EXTERNAL_URL = os.getenv("EXTERNAL_URL")


def start_command_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text(f'Hello {update.effective_user.first_name}')


def message_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    exp = re.compile('https://example.com/(\d{7,})/\w+', re.IGNORECASE)

    m = exp.match(update.message.text)
    if m is None:
        update.message.reply_text(f'Unable to recognize a link')
        return

    lines = ["here is your result:"]

    # some magic here

    update.message.reply_html('\n'.join(lines))


def main():
    u = Updater(TELEGRAM_API_KEY)
    u.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command_handler))
    u.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & Filters.chat_type.private, message_handler))

    u.start_webhook(listen='0.0.0.0', port=80, webhook_url=EXTERNAL_URL)
    u.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: IIRC, you need a web hook to receive messages from the bot

Comment: I’m receiving messages, buy notification is going late, in 1-3minutes.

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: @hd1, sure, please take a look